# Why is List a Semigroup but Seq is not?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scalaz7

I'm fairly new to scalaz and I am trying to figure out why the following code works:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
scala> Map[String,List[String]]() |+| Map[String,List[String]]()
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map()
```

but this doesn't...

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
scala> Map[String,Seq[String]]() |+| Map[String,Seq[String]]()
<console>:14: error: value |+| is not a member of      scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[String]]
          Map[String,Seq[String]]() |+| Map[String,Seq[String]]()
```

I see the Map implicit for Semigroup, but I don't see the one for List or Seq.

Couple questions:

1. Where is the implicit for ListSemigroup?
2. Why isn't there one for Seq?

Comment: What version are you using? Your tags suggest, you are asking about scalaz-seven, while the link to Semigroup.scala leads to master, which is 6.x.

Comment: I am indeed using 7.  I'll fix my link.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So, in Scalaz 7 there's an [implicit `List` to  `Monoid` function](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/List.scala#L83) which gives you back a `Monoid[List[A]]`. `Monoid` extends `SemiGroup` so we have List covered.

`Seq` does not get this special treatment. There's no implicit conversion from `Seq` to `Monoid` or `Semigroup`. There is an [implicit `IndexedSeq` to `Monoid`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/IndexedSeq.scala#L35), but this doesn't help us.

Why isn't there one for Seq? I don't know. Perhaps Seq violates some laws of monoids/semigroups so there is no conversion. It seems like there were issues with Seq in Scalaz 6 so they've removed some features:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/scalaz/Seq/scalaz/Deaec1H11W4/gYFSquXjTzYJ

**UPDATE**

Looking at the scala doc it becomes more apparent why the scalaz folks went this way. [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) inherits LinearSeq which inherits Seq. [IndexedSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq) inherits Seq. If they were to provide a semigroup for Seq, it could override any other semigroup on IndexedSeq or LinearSeq and loose performance advantages between the two. If you look at the scalaz signatures for append you can see that they take advantage of these performance differences:

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/List.scala

```
  implicit def listMonoid[A]: Monoid[List[A]] = new Monoid[List[A]] {
    def append(f1: List[A], f2: => List[A]) = f1 ::: f2
    def zero: List[A] = Nil
  }
```

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/IndexedSeq.scala

```
implicit def ixSqMonoid[A]: Monoid[IxSq[A]] = new Monoid[IxSq[A]] {
    def append(f1: IxSq[A], f2: => IxSq[A]) = f1 ++ f2
    def zero: IxSq[A] = empty
  }
```

If we dig deeper, we see that Seq only implements [++](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L144) which has worse performance on lists than [:::](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L124) for append operations. So, to answer your second question, performance. If scalaz implemented semigroup for Seq it would most likely lead to ambiguous performance as you would only be able to optimize for indexed. Iterable has the same issue.

Comment: Great answer to the question about where the one is for list. It seems all iterables should be at least semigroups...

Comment: If you look at the scala doc, Seq is the base for LinearSeq and IndexedSeq which both have different performance differences. List inherits LinearSeq, so I can see why they had to choose List and IndexedSeq instead of Seq. I'll see if I can update this more concisely.

Comment: In addition to what is already said here, you can have a look at this example: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/e38ce2c79583e2a3dc24b92ba117b7dba76d9725/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/IsomorphismUsage.scala It uses `Isomorphism` to derive instances for `Seq` from a `List`. Use it at your own risk: as per Jason Zaugg, instances for `Seq` are dangerous.