# Implicit conversion from Traversable to Foldable in Scalaz 7

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

Where is the implicit conversion from a `scala.collection.Traversable[A]` to a `scalaz.Foldable[A]` defined in Scalaz 7.x? The standard import

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

does not include it.

There used to be an `implicit def TraversableFoldable[]...` defined in `scalaz/Foldable.scala`, but

Relevant implicits used to be defined in `scalaz/Foldable.scala`, but have been moved into

```
scalaz.std.list
scalaz.std.iterable
...
```

`scalaz.std.traversable` does not exist, though. Perhaps this is an accidental omission?

FWIW, `scalaz.std.list` is included by the standard import, so a `List[A]` converts to a `Foldable[A]`.  `scalaz.std.iterable` is not in the standard import and must be explicitly imported.to convert `Iterable[A]` to `Foldable[A]` implicitly.

Comment: Let me Github that for you: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/search?q=Foldable&ref=cmdform

Comment: @wheaties I did that search before posting!  Really! I didn't find anything useful---I'm hopeful someone knows enough to tell me either what replaced TraversableFoldable or that its omission is a bug.

Comment: Is Traversable not a `Semigroup`? Take a look to find out where the implicit from `Semigroup` to `Traversable` is found. That could be the issue. That or try to use the more general `TraversableLike[A, Repr]` where you bound `Repr : SemiGroup`.

Comment: Why is `Semigroup` relevant here?

Comment: `Semigroup` has an implicit conversion to `Foldable`.

Comment: Are you sure `Semigroup` has an implicit conversion to `Foldable`? Semigroups aren't naturally enumerable unless equipped with a generator. Here, `Semigroup[A]` is just endowing the type `A` with a binary operation `(A,A) -> A`, witnessing that `A` is a semigroup under that operation. There's no requirement in `Semigroup[A]` that a generator exist.

Comment: See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15624788/334519) or [this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/scalaz/Seq/scalaz/Deaec1H11W4/gYFSquXjTzYJ) for some discussion of the closely related question of why there isn't a `Traverse` instance for `Seq` (which is even lower in the inheritance hierarchy). In short there's a kind of impedence mismatch between the way the standard collections library relies so heavily on subtyping and the abstractions used in Scalaz.

Comment: @TravisBrown Interesting.  Does prioritized implicits not solve this issue (e.g., the Seq -> Traverse implicit would have lower priority than the List -> Traverse implicit)?