# Conditional logic when evaluating two Options

Tags: scala

Is there a more idiomatic/simpler way to write this code that deals with two Options?

```
object Test extends App {
  val colors = Some(1)
  val sizes = Some(2)

  val ids = colors match {
    case None => {
      sizes match {
        case None => getRegularIds
        case Some(sizes) => getSizeIds
      }
    }
    case Some(colors) => {
      sizes match {
        case None => getColorIds
        case Some(sizes) => getColorIds ++ getSizeIds
      }
    }
  }

  println(ids)

  def getColorIds = Seq(1,2,4)
  def getSizeIds = Seq(4,5,6)
  def getRegularIds = Seq(7,8,9)
}
```

Scala is so concise that it leads me to think there's probably a cleaner way to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid nested matching:

```
val ids2 = (colors, sizes) match {
  case (None, None)       => getRegularIds
  case (Some(_), None)    => getColorIds
  case (None, Some(_))    => getSizeIds
  case (Some(_), Some(_)) => getColorIds ++ getSizeIds
}
```

You also could try something like:

```
colors.fold(defaultColors)(_ => getColors) ++ 
  sizes.fold(defaultSizes)(_ => getSizes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Much cleaner.

Comment: On the other hand, nested logic is faster, since it results in a shallower branches.

Comment: @PaulDraper Even if so, this 0.0000001% of performance gain doesn't outweigh maintainability.

Comment: @ipoteka, in this case, sure. I was just pointing out that nested branches shouldn't always be avoided. Avoiding linear time branch resolution can be important in some cases, e.g. Scala's [@switch](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.annotation.switch).

Answer (score 0):

If your `Seq`s are `List`s, you can also do this with Scalaz's Semigroup append, right out of the box:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

scala> (colors.map(_ => getColorIds) |+| sizes.map(_ => getSizeIds))
         .getOrElse(getRegularIds)
res11: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6)
```

Here are the other outcomes (explicitly) to show what's going on:

```
scala> (Option(List(1, 2, 4)) |+| Option.empty[List[Int]]).getOrElse(getRegularIds)
res14: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)

scala> (Option.empty[List[Int]] |+| Option(List(4, 5, 6))).getOrElse(getRegularIds)
res15: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> (Option.empty[List[Int]] |+| Option.empty[List[Int]]).getOrElse(getRegularIds)
res16: List[Int] = List(7, 8, 9)
```

Unfortunately, there is no `Semigroup[Seq]`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15624788/2292812) for a better explanation as to why not.