# Why scalaz |+| operator only doesn't work with Maps which value are Seq?

Tags: scala, scalaz, seq, monoids, semigroup

I have two maps as follows.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val map1: Map[String, Seq[String]] = Some value
val map2: Map[String, Seq[String]] = Somve Value
```

This compiles fine and everything works as expected.

```
// Compiles
map1.mapValues{_.toList} |+| map2.mapValues{_.toList}
```

But this one doesn't compile (cannot resolve symbol `|+|`), I'm wondering why?

```
// Doesn't compile
map1 |+| map2
```

**Update**: I found this great article that answers why the compile error happens and that's basically, as people mentioned in comment section, `Seq` is not a monoid: [Why is List a Semigroup but Seq is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623585/why-is-list-a-semigroup-but-seq-is-not)

Now my question is: Does that mean I have to convert my `Seq` (`IndexedSeq` have the same problem) to `List` and back to `Seq` again (the `Seq`s are actually `IndexedSeq` and I should keep them as `IndexedSeq` for performance reasons). Is there any work around this other than writing my own map merger code?

Comment: Guessing: Seq aren't monoids.

Comment: `Seq` doesn't have monoid instance. Monoid for map needs a monoid for type of values (or a semigroup, not sure how exactly it is done in scalaz).

Comment: Does that mean I have to convert my seq to list and back to IndexSeq again (the seqs are actually indexSeq and I should keep them as IndexSeq for performance reasons). Is there any work around this other than writing my own map merger code?

Comment: From the answer you linked to in your update, it sounds like there's a monoid instance for `IndexedSeq`. So could you `toIndexedSeq` the values instead (which should hopefully be a no-op if the `Seq` is already an `IndexedSeq`)?

Comment: Even using `IndexedSeq` doesn't work. Same error.